# Validate protobuf messages using JSON Schema?

Tags: json, validation, protocol-buffers

My team is trying to understand how to best use **protobuf** in our product. We like the idea of having language-neutral object definitions to base (de)serialization on. At the same time we want to validate values of fields in the messages transported between our various services.

It appears protobuf has opted to remove the `required` and `optional` fields in **proto3**. So far we've used [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org) for validation. It gives you a way to put constraints on which values fields can have.

We're considering using both **protobuf** and **JSON Schema** together. One to define the messages we're transmitting in a language neutral way (protobuf), and one to validate the values in these messages (json-schema).

**It feels like we're duplicating work by doing this. Is there an easier way to accomplish what we're describing?**